# Is this the best way to pan to (x,y) using D3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, zooming

I have a vector map containing smaller svg figures within it and I'm trying to figure out the best way to zoom+pan to these figures when the user selects one of them.

Since I have the coordinates for them, I figured I can use them in my function to translate the container SVG but it's not working quite right. Ideally, the figure would be centered in the view.

```
function zoomOnDev() {
  d3.select('#TRNF1X16Y88W ellipse').transition().style("fill","cornflowerblue");

  d3.select('#content').transition().duration(750)
    .call(zoom.translateTo, 16, 88); // 16, 88 would the dynamic x,y coordinates
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this with D3? [Here's my full codepen](https://codepen.io/janbe30/pen/PoXzXZW?editors=1010)